# MITM a Connection Between Components on a Motherboard

Tags: physical-attacks

I have been thinking about it lately and was wondering if a Man In The Middle attack could be established physically on a motherboard.

The goal would be to intercept the signals between two components and to manipulate the signals as well. I assume this could be done through drilling holes in the circuit, and having a separate device bridge a new connection.

Would this be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing a [brute forcing device for iPhones a little while ago](https://www.cultofmac.com/316532/this-brute-force-device-can-crack-any-iphones-pin-code/). There is also a device out there for breaking BIOS passwords on certain thinkpads by connecting to an IC of some sort but I can't find the article.

Although those methods probably differ in some aspects from a MITM attack, the way you describe would seem perfectly valid based on those devices.